# Command button without ajax invokes @PostConstruct on second click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton, postconstruct

I have a page with few buttons one of which is used to generate and download (show download popup window) excel stylesheet. Ajax is set to `ajax=false` on a `<p:commandButton>` because with ajax enabled the download window was not showing.
Button validates if user did everything to be able to download excel and if not then it updates message area showing error popup message through primefaces`<p:growl>`.
My problem is with button being clicked for second time. After first click, if the validation method resolves to false, the error message is showing without any problems but after a second click the method is not being invoked at all and the `@PostConstruct` initialize method is invoked so the whole page reloads thus clearing all user inputs.

Here's `.xhtml` file piece of code:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="aqua-button btn-style"
        actionListener="#{symulujHarmonogramSplat.downloadSchedule}"
        update="messages" ajax="false"
        value='#{activePreferencesBean.portletResourcesProvider["view.label.button.downloadSchedule"]}'></p:commandButton>
```

Here's code of backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "symulujHarmonogramSplat")
@ExpireWithPageFlow
@SessionScoped
public class SymulujHarmonogramSplat {
    /**
     * Action button handler - DownloadSchedule
     */
    public void downloadSchedule() {
        log.info(getClass().getName() + ": downloadSchedule() invoked !");
        if (screenLogic.isAllowToDownloadSchedule()) {
            xlsManager.downloadSchedule(applicationData,
                    loanData.getCalculateFinancialDetailsData().getInstallmentList(),
                    loanData.getCalculateFinancialDetailsData());
        }
    }
}
```

The bean's method `downloadSchedule()` calls another bean's method `screenLogic.isAllowToDownloadSchedule()`.
Here's code for second bean:

```java
@SessionScoped
@ExpireWithPageFlow
@ManagedBean(name = "symulujHarmonogramSplatLogic")
public class SymulujHarmonogramSplatLogic {
    public boolean isAllowToDownloadSchedule() {
        if (!isSimCompleted) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Nie wykonano symulacji.", ""));
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Second bean checks if user completed required action and returns true or shows error message accordingly.
My question is what could I do do prevent page to initialize itself after second click (so enforce to invoke `actionListener` method for each subsequent call).

Edit 1: It doesn't matter if backing bean's method actually do anything (show message for that matter) or not. If after page reloads after first click I click it second time it always invokes PostConstruct init.

Comment: what do you mean by second click : Double click ???

Comment: First click: bean's method invoked, page reloads (since it's no-ajax), popup window with message shows up. 
Second click: click button once again after it finished reloading and everything after first click. I dont know if that makes sense

Comment: you can lock it after one click

Comment: @YagamiLight By lock you mean disable it ? So it is unclickable ? I cannot do that unfortunately

Comment: the solution that i propose is to make a transient boolean value that change after the first click , are you interested with this solution

Comment: @YagamiLight Yes, could you elaborate ?

Comment: Please, [mcve]! And try without '@ExpireWithPageFlow`